# Regex: there's a regex inside

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm falling deeper into the regex's dark side. I need to parse this:

```
{{word(a|b|c)|word$1}}
{{word(s?)|word$1}}
{{w(a|b|c)ord(s?)|w$1ord$2}}
```

As you may have noticed, it is a search & replace scheme, containing regular expressions.
The wikimedia engine does it very well, but I couldn't find how it does: [right here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia%3aListe_de_fautes_d%27orthographe_courantes).

I just need to get the first part, and the second part into two seperated variables. For instance:

```
preg_match(REGEX, "{{word(a|b|c)|word$1}}", $result) // Applying REGEX on this
echo $result[1] // word(a|b|c)
echo $result[2] // word$1
```

How would you do ? It's like regex in regex, I'm completely lost...

Comment: So you're trying to capture the literal string `{{word(a|b|c)` as opposed to a regex matching two curly brackets followed by 'word' followed by either 'a', 'b' or 'c', right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the parts using something like:

```
{{((?:(?!}}).)+)\|([^|]+?)}}
```

Note that if you are allowing arbitrary PCRE regex then some very complex and slow patterns can be constructed, possibly allowing simple DoS attacks on your site.

Comment: @ldiqual `(?: )` is a non-capturing expression (so there's no [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to it); `(?! )` is a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, and `(?!}})` is a negative lookahead, that construct matches a string that does not contain `}}`.

Comment: This solution however will not work if the second part contains an escaped pipe.

Comment: The second part won't. Thank you everyone !

Comment: @ldiqual If the string only contains one simple tag the expression can be simplified: `{{(.+)\|([^|]*)}}`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how deep the nesting can be, but you can just split it by `|`, taking care not to split it by any `|` within parentheses. Here's the easy way, I suppose:

```
$str = 'word(a|b|c)|word$1'; // Trim off the leading and trailing {{ and }}
$items = explode('|', $str);
$realItems = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    $realItem = $items[$i];
    while(substr_count($realItem, '(') > substr_count($realItem, ')')) {
        // Glue them together and skip one!
        $realItem .= '|' . $items[++$i];
    }

    $realItems[] = $realItem;
}
```

Now `$realItems[]` contains your 2-4 key values, which you can simply pass into `preg_replace`; it'll do all the work for you.

Comment: I tried your solution, but `(a|b|c)` gives `(abc)`. This works: `$realItem .= $items[++$i] ."|";` and then `$realItems[] = rtrim($realItem, "|");`. Anyway, nice and clever answer ;)

Comment: @ldiqual: You don't need to trim it, just put it before :) Edited anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not that hard.

The thing is, the replacement string will only ever contain an escaped `|`, ie `\|`.

And for one of these very few occasions, `.*` will actually be useful here.

Do: `preg_match("^{{(.*)\|([^|]+(?:\\\|[^|]*)*)}}$", $result);`, this should do what you want.

The trick here is the second group: it is, again, the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern, where `normal` is `[^|]` (anything but a pipe), and `special` is `\\\|` (a backslash followed by a pipe).